# keep single space line in srt file by removing ctrl-m characters and double empty line

Tags: linux, awk, text-processing, srt

we process a lot of srt files in linux to generate derivatives , but some of them have <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>M</kbd> characters since they were generated in windows. right now I put two commands to check and take out the hidden characters

```
tr -d '\015' <${file}.srt >${file}.srt

awk '/^$/{ if (! blank++) print; next } { blank=0; print }'  ${file}.srt | tee ${file}.srt
```

but I still have srt files that slips through the command and still have <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>M</kbd> character in it. Does anyone have a solution in this case to keep on empty line only between each subtle lines? so if pre-processed srt file looks like

```
1
00:00:05,569 --> 00:00:07,569
Welcome to this overview of ShareStream, 


2
00:00:07,820 --> 00:00:11,940
which is a new digital streaming service
from Information Technology Services


3
00:00:11,940 --> 00:00:13,740
at the University of Iowa.
```

after taking out the ctrl-M character or extra space line should be

```
1
00:00:05,569 --> 00:00:07,569
Welcome to this overview of ShareStream, 

2
00:00:07,820 --> 00:00:11,940
which is a new digital streaming service
from Information Technology Services

3
00:00:11,940 --> 00:00:13,740
at the University of Iowa.
```

any help is appreciated thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The UNIX command to remove those  line-end control-Ms is

```
dos2unix
```

The UNIX command to squeeze multiple blank lines between records to one blank line is:

```
awk -v RS= -v ORS='\n\n' '1'
```

Comment: I tend to use `sed -i 's/\r$//' file`, but that probably requires GNU sed.

Comment: @glennjackman it'd require OSX or GNU sed for the `-i`, but of course you don' t **need** that, and I'm not sure what POSIX says about `\r` but I'd suspect it has to be something like `'s/'$'\r''$//'` (but then you're bash-only which may not be any more portable) or use a literal control-M. You could use `awk '{sub(/\r$/,"")}1'` of course and that'd work anywhere,